# How to remove app from iOS by name

Tags: ios, applications

I know that I can remove app by long tapping on any icon on desktop and then tap the cross sign. But what if I have many apps and don’t want to waste my time to scroll among desktops to find specific app. I can find any app by search by name via drop down on desktop. Unfortunately in this case there is no ability to delete app (I didn’t find it), only to run. How can I remove app quickly only knowing its name?

Comment: Sadly, you can’t. You can use storage settings or an external tool like MDM or Apple Configurator or iTunes but not iOS to do this. What’s the reason for removing an app quickly? Perhaps something else is needed.

Comment: @bmike because I can in Android :)

Comment: Got it, just because you want that feature. Fair enough.

Comment: @bmike the real case: today I followed some instagram link on my iPad, the app (actually it’s supported for iPhone only) been opened, but due to logged out I couldn’t see a content. I decided to remove the app (actually I never used it) to open link in browser, and here is my question appeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings > General > iPhone Storage > (App Name) > Delete App

[image: apps listed by name]

[image: optionto delete the app]

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but in this case apps are sorted by the occupied space, i.e. still hard to find app by name.

Comment: @alex. If there were a way to sort by name, Matt or I would have answered. This is the best you get on iOS 11. Spotlight can find an app but won’t let you delete or see what springboard folder or screen has the app. You need iTunes or MDM or Apple Configurator to remove and sort apps other than the icon or this interface.

Comment: @bmike came here from google today :) on ipad os 14.2 there is magnifier icon on the top right side of the storage page, so searching by name is now possible.

Answer (score 0):

The iPad multitasking allows for a hack. You can search for the app in spotlight, long press the result to drag, then drag it to the nearest spot on your iPad icon screen, then delete it from there.

Does not work on iPhone though, and it still is awful versus the ease of doing this on Android :(

Comment: I can drag, but dropping do nothing. Could you please add a video/gif to clarify chain of actions?

Comment: It only works on iPad that supports multitasking

Comment: I have iPad, but can’t do what you said in this answer. Maybe I did something wrong, hence I’m asking you for clarification.